# Angularjs, Expressjs and passportjs for authentication checks on server side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I have a Node.js application where I have used Yeoman scaffolding for Angular. I am also using ExpressJS for server side.

So basically my app structure is:

```
app
  -->views
      --> more files
server.js
```

The structure is more heavy than this, but this is to keep it simple.

Basically I have used PassportJS on the server side for authentication. The routing is currently being carried out via AngularJS routing parameters.

I have come across an issue now as I need to carry out authentication by using a middleware method:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log('authenticate=' + req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        return next(); 
    }
    res.redirect('/')
}
```

I have created an `app.get` on the server side to check if the user tries to get to the admin page without logging in:

```
app.get('/admin', ensureAuthenticated,
    function(req, res){
        console.log('get admin' + req.params);
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/app/views/admin/users.html');
    });
```

But it never goes to the method. What am I doing wrong?

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return res.send(401, 'User is not authorized');
        }
        next();
```

Comment: Hi, the authentication works if i just put /admin but my url is localhost:8888/#/admin. It never hits the route in express if i type the url in as shown

Comment: localhost:8888/#/admin is angular realm so you should change your logic I think ie put your view in admin path

Comment: I have a further issue now which is when I route to the admin page i press refresh on the browser and it tries to render the page but it states No default engine was specified. I am just using html pages?

Comment: imo all in all it's more easy/secure to manage admin side server side and not in angularjs that is quite hard

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was not working was because angularjs locationprovider was not set to htmlmode5 when configuring the routes on the client side. The following line was added:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This basically removes the '#' from the url.